# python selenium im getting an multiple errors in my class?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, robotframework

I'm new to Python, and I'm trying to modify SeleniumLibrary from robotframwork to meet my own needs. Unfortunately,l I'm getting multiple errors and I don't know why.

There are multiple functions to call different browsers with binary path and headless option.

```
import os

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities



DEFAULT_BROWSR = 'chrome'

DRIVERS_PATH = os.path.join( os.getcwd() , "\drivers\\" )

BROWSER_NAMES = {
    'ff': "_make_ff",
    'firefox': "_make_ff",
    'headlessfirefox': '_make_headless_ff',
    'gc': "_make_chrome",
    'googlechrome': "_make_chrome",
    'headlesschrome': '_make_headless_chrome',
    'chrome': "_make_chrome",
}

BROWSER_PATHS = {
    '_make_ff': "geckodriver-win32\geckodriver.exe",
    '_make_headless_ff': "geckodriver-win32\geckodriver.exe",
    '_make_chrome': "chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe",
    '_make_headless_chrome': "chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe",
}

class driver(object):

    """docstring for driver"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = None
        self.driver_path = None
        self.timeout = 20
        self.implicit_wait = 5

    def create(self,browser_name=DEFAULT_BROWSR):
        return self._make_driver(browser_name)

    def _make_driver(self, browser_name, desired_capabilities=None, profile_dir=None, remote=None):
        creation_func = self._get_driver_creation_function(browser_name)
        driver_path = self._get_driver_path(browser_name)

        desired_capabilities = {"chrome.binary": driver_path,}

        driver = creation_func(remote, desired_capabilities, profile_dir)

        driver.set_script_timeout(self.timeout)
        driver.implicitly_wait(self.implicit_wait)
        return driver

    """ Return browser function name """
    def _get_driver_creation_function(self,browser_name):
        try:
            func_name = BROWSER_NAMES[browser_name]
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError(browser_name + " is not a supported browser.")
        return getattr(self, func_name)

    """ Return browser driver path """
    def _get_driver_path(self,browser_name):
        try:
            func_name = self._get_driver_creation_function(browser_name)
            driver_path = os.path.join(DRIVERS_PATH , BROWSER_PATHS[func_name])
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError(browser_name + " is not a supported browser.")
        return getattr(self, driver_path)

    """ Used inside driver creation functions """
    def _generic_make_driver(self, webdriver_type, desired_cap_type, remote_url, desired_caps, options=None):
        if is_falsy(remote_url):
            if options is None:
                driver = webdriver_type()
            else:
                driver = webdriver_type(options=options)
        else:
            driver = self._create_remote_web_driver(desired_cap_type, remote_url, desired_caps, options=options)

        return driver

    def _create_remote_web_driver(self, capabilities_type, remote_url, desired_capabilities=None, profile=None, options=None):
        desired_capabilities_object = capabilities_type.copy()

        if not isinstance(desired_capabilities, dict):
            desired_capabilities = self._parse_capabilities_string(desired_capabilities)

        desired_capabilities_object.update(desired_capabilities or {})

        return webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities_object, 
            command_executor=str(remote_url), browser_profile=profile,
            options=options)

    def _make_ff(self, remote, desired_capabilities, profile_dir, options=None):
        if is_falsy(profile_dir):
            profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        else:
            profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile_dir)

        if is_truthy(remote):
            driver = self._create_remote_web_driver(webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX, remote,
                desired_capabilities, profile, options=options)
        else:
            driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options, **self._geckodriver_log_config)
        return driver

    def _make_headless_ff(self, remote, desired_capabilities, profile_dir):
        options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        options.set_headless()
        return self._make_ff(remote, desired_capabilities, profile_dir, options=options)

    def _make_chrome(self, remote, desired_capabilities, profile_dir, options=None):
        return self._generic_make_driver(
        webdriver.Chrome, webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME, remote,
        desired_capabilities, options=options)

    def _make_headless_chrome(self, remote, desired_capabilities, profile_dir):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.set_headless()
        return self._make_chrome(remote, desired_capabilities, profile_dir, options)
```

This function should open a browser which will call the default chrome driver:

```
driver().create()
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver().create()
  File "C:\Users\modules\driver.py", line 52, in create
    return self._make_driver(browser_name)
  File "C:\Users\modules\driver.py", line 56, in _make_driver
    driver_path = self._get_driver_path(browser_name)
  File "C:\Users\modules\driver.py", line 80, in _get_driver_path
    raise ValueError(browser_name + " is not a supported browser.")
ValueError: chrome is not a supported browser.

Comment: please [edit] your question to include the stack trace. Code and stack traces are very hard to read in the comment section.

Comment: I recommend you print the error that you're catching. You're hiding the real exception by raising your own. Just the most basic of debugging will show you the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted in the comments, this kind of issues can be easily resolved by using a properly configured Python IDE with debugging capabilities. There are several good ones, both open source and commercial.

In this particular case your script has two problems:

Missing Import:

```
from robot.utils import is_falsy
```

Function that needs a bit of rewriting as the `func_name` needs to be a different value.

```
""" Return browser driver path """
def _get_driver_path(self,browser_name):
    try:
        #func_name = self._get_driver_creation_function(browser_name)
        driver_path = os.path.join(DRIVERS_PATH , BROWSER_PATHS[BROWSER_NAMES[browser_name]])
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError(browser_name + " is not a supported browser.")
    return driver_path
```